# Webdriver keeps disconnecting after a while of running

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I made a webscraper with python and selenium. After a while the webdriver disconnects and stops my code.

I tried to use a try and except block:

```
try:
    #my code that uses webdriver
except WebDriverException as e:
    print("An exception occurred:", type(e).__name__, e)
    reconnect = True
if reconnect == True:
    reconnect = False
    print("set reconnect to false")
    driver.quit()
    print("killed chrome")
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={ua.random}')
    print("Randomized header")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)
    print("set driver")
    driver.get(safetyurl)
    print("went to safetyurl")
    pageNav.send_keys(x)
    print("sent keys")
    pageNav.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    print("went to the page after the safetyurl")
```

There were two problems I had: First, the code paused when it was on the driver.quit() line. After closing chrome manually, the script continued until I got some error messages when I tried to send keys:

```
WebDriverException Message: disconnected: not connected to DevTools
  (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)
  (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.105)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001502E3CAC10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=64600): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/0a6c0b88737f5174e0699fdc0b195563/element/9f7e6316-0560-477b-babd-53197995d9f0/value (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001502E3CAC10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

Comment: I’m having a similar issue. Every time I leave it running, the next day it has disconnected from the WebDriver: ‘Message: disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools) (Session info: chrome=117.0.5938.150)’